# When is a transformation not linear?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'd like an intuitive answer to the following question, and not the usual rule of checking:

$$T(u+v)=T(u)+T(v) \quad\text{and}\quad T(cu)=cT(u)$$

When there is a matrix transformation such as

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    a & x & d \\
    b & y & e \\
    c & z & f \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
for any relevant vector X, then it is clear that the transformation is linear. But when is it the case that such a matrix exists but the transformation is not linear? And why? Does linear dependence has any relationship with this?  I am clearly asking if there's a matrix transformation which is non linear.

Comment: What is the matrix of a non-linear transformation?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand well your question, but a matrix does always represent a linear transformation.

Comment: "that such a matrix exists" this means nothing if you don't specify the relationship between the matrix and the transformation.

Comment: What you're saying amounts to this: You want to know how to check whether $T$ is linear without checking whether $T$ is linear. Good luck with that.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich , no, it's as Jose pointed, what's the matrix of a non linear transformation? Is there something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *define* you transformation with something like $T(u)= Au$, with $A$ a matrix, then the transformation is always linear, no matter what $A$ you pick. The problem arise when you define it with different mathematical objects, such as an arbitrary formula:
$$
T(x,y) = x^2- x + 4y.
$$
Then it is quite easy to check if the given formula makes a linear o a non-linear transformation, for example by checking additivity:
$$
T(x+x', y+y') = (x+x')^2 - x-x' +4y + 4y'\\
= x^2 + x'^2 + 2xx' - x - x' + 4y + 4y' \neq T(x,y) + T(x',y') = x^2 -x+4y + x'^2 -x' +4y'.
$$
A good heuristic is: a linear function is usually a composition of 'primitive' linear functions (like sum and product). If squares, exponentials or other stuff appears, it probably isn't linear.

Comment: Is the statement, "If you define a transformation with something like T(u)=Au, with A a matrix, then the transformation is always linear no matter what A you pick", stated in a theorem?" If it is, it solves all of the question, However, I couldn't find anything like this in my book.

Comment: It is certainly a theorem. Maybe not a Very Important Theorem With A Name, but nonetheless. For the finite-dimensional case the theorem is even stronger: linear transformations are those and only those which admit that kind of representation.

Comment: found it: https://www.mathbootcamps.com/proof-every-matrix-transformation-is-a-linear-transformation/ . Thanks and for future ones include link in your answer.